# how to implement failover of apache httpd that is working as the loadbalancer for multiple tomcat instances

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I am implementing almost 3 tomcat instances with the load balanced by apache httpd and mod_jk in on single machine. I also configured session affinity and session replication in the tomcat instances. So, even though, any one of the 3 tomcat instances goes down, there would be no worry.

But as I am balancing the load for 3 tomcat instances by a single apache httpd, if the apache httpd fails and if its service goes down, then it becomes again a single point of failure.

So, how to get rid of this problem? How can I do failover of the apache httpd which inturn works as the load balancer for multiple tomcats.

Answer (score 0):

I have used cloud load balancers before (AWS). And they passed East US power failure. [google](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/)